# How should I read a format string of variable length in C++ from stdin?

Tags: c++, io

sorry for such a stupid question but I couldn't find any obvious answer.

I need to read from `stdin` first an `int` `n` with the size of an array, and then integer values from a string in the format "1 2 3 4 5 6" with `n` elements.

If I knew the number of parameters at compile time I could use something like a `scanf` (or the safe alternatives) with a format string like `"%d %d %d %d %d %d"`, but here I will only know that value at run time.

What would be the best way to do this in C++? Performance is important but more than that safety.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`, and read it. `scanf`, and format strings are for C, and modern C++ should use type-safe `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I read a format string of variable length in C++ from stdin?

You should not attempt to do such thing. Only ever use constant format strings.

> I need to read from stdin first an int n with the size of an array, and then integer values
>
> What would be the best way to do this in C++?

Read one value at a time. Repeat using a loop.

Comment: I have no choice, my input is a string in that format.

Comment: @memememe You can read that input string with algorithm that I described.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what errorika describes:

```
const int SIZE = //as much of your memory as you'd like the user to have access to
***caller function must include this:
   //allocate a string to hold some data;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    buffer = malloc (SIZE * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("malloc error terminating\n");
        return;
    }
***
void getEntry(char* buffer) {
    int count = 0;
    int maxlen = SIZE - 1;
    char a = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        buffer[i] = '0';
    }

    while (a != '\n' && count < maxlen) {
            a = fgetc(stdin);
            buffer[count] = a;
            count++;
    }
    if (a == '\n') {
        buffer[count - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        buffer[count] = '\0';
        do {
                a = fgetc(stdin);
        } while (a != '\n');
    }
}
```

This is all basic C code but user entry is evil. Here is what I've come up with for more C++ idiomatic user input functions (query is just the message string you pass in):

```
template<typename T>
void getInput(const std::string query, T& entry) {
    std::string input;
    std::cout << query << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, input);
    std::stringstream buffer{input};
    buffer >> entry;
}
```

OR

```
template<typename T>
void getInput2(std::string query, T& entry) {
    bool validInput = false;
    while (validInput == false)
    { 
        validInput = true;
        std::cout << query << std::endl;
        std::cin >> entry;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            validInput = false;
            std::cout << "Unacceptable entry\n" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is T a template I should define myself, or the template in which I want to store the parsed values?